# Spring web app add Javascript and CSS to HTML file

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, war

I'm having some trouble adding javascript and css files to my maven, spring webapp project.

I'm bin searching the web and here, but having issues putting it all in the right place.

What I want to do, is to have a index.html page in the root context, and from it, reference to a local javascript file in the system

.war layout

```
war/
  index.html
  js/
    javascript.js
  css/
    default.css
  WEB-INF/
    classes/
      *.classes
    lib/
      *.jar
    springapp-servlet.xml
    web.xml
```

index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>springTest</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- View resolvers -->

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="velocityConfig"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    </bean>

<!-- controllers and java service beans -->
.....

<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />

</beans>
```

Now I thought that this would make the js and css dirs available for linking in the html file, but i just get a plain text and no query-mobile view.

Running it in Jboss AS 7 with Spring and Maven.

best regards
Henrik

Comment: what do you mean by "but i just get a plain text and no query-mobile view" ? If you inspect the generated html, what do you see ? any errors (404 or else), do you see the imported files ?

Comment: The files are in the war, jquerymobile both css and js.... Will check the console out asap.

Comment: of course they are, but what does firebug or chrome console print out ? Do you see these files in those downloaded by your browser ?

Comment: Its as you sad, I get 404 not found for my web address.

Comment: which one it can"t find ?

Comment: It can't find the css file nor the js files. 
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/example/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css"

Comment: so your CSS file is not in the right place

Comment: That was the thing, created several copies and added them on different places and when I started removing them it started working... I'm not clear why....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, gotten it working, somehow, with the structure I had....

Comment: Thats the thing, i did not change anything....
Although there was something strange with the JQuery-mobile so I change them to the online refs and just have my local changes/overrides added...